# Bind to element within an iframe (same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got an iframe which i'm dynamically inserting into the page. Then I want to bind to a button within that iframe to trigger a page refresh on the parent page.

Is this possible? Both are on the same domain.

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="cacheBuster" src="http://lol.com/system/page.aspx" style="position: absolute; top:0; right:0; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #fff" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

var cacheIframe = $('#cacheBuster');

cacheIframe.live('mouseover', function()  {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width : 300, height : 300});
    });

cacheIframe.contents().find('#buttonid').live('click',function() {
    alert('cleared!');
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This is being posted as a comment and not an answer because I've never really tried this, but if I understand correctly, you need something like cacheIframe.document.body.live(...

Comment: If you tried it, did it work?

Comment: I said I haven't had the chance to try it.  I only remember seeing that as necessary in the tutorials I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just make:

`window.location.reload();` ==> `window.parent.location.reload();`

you can achieve the described functionality.

although, if the code is running in the outer window then your code should already work because the `window` in scope is that of the parent. Have you tried it yet?

**EDIT:**
ok, this is probably easier to do without jquery.

```
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
ifr.src = "http://google.com/";

document.body.appendChild(ifr);
button = ifr.contentDocument.createElement('a');
button.onclick = "window.parent.location.reload();" //you could prob use jquery here
ifr.contentDocument.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Yeah, thats not the question. The code is running in the parent, I want to know if its possible to bind to an element within the iframe..

Comment: Yeah, as long as its in the same domain